# Firebase Cloud Firestore query not finding my document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here's a picture of my data:
[image]

I'm trying to get that document. This works:

```
var docRef = db.collection('users').doc('jPDKwHyrFNXNTFI5qgOY');
docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
  if (doc.exists) {
    console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
  } else {
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

It returns:

[image]

I.e., if I know the document's key I can get the document.

This doesn't work:

```
db.collection('users').where('uid', '==', 'bcmrZDO0X5N6kB38MqhUJZ11OzA3')
.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  if (querySnapshot.exists) {
    console.log(querySnapshot.data);
  } else {
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log("Error getting document: ", error);
});
```

It just returns `No such document!` What's wrong with my query?

Comment: Please tag with the languages used for code. This is JavaScript.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The difference in your two requests is that in the first case you are retrieving one document which gives you a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) which has the `exists` property and the `data()` method.

In the second case you do a query, which gives you a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) that has to be handled differently from a `DocumentSnapshot`. Instead of a single document you get a list/collection of documents. You can check if data has been retrieved using the `empty` or `size` properties, and then go through the results using the `forEach` method or going through the `docs` array:

```
db.collection('users').where('uid', '==', 'bcmrZDO0X5N6kB38MqhUJZ11OzA3')
.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  if (querySnapshot.size > 0) {
    // Contents of first document
    console.log(querySnapshot.docs[0].data());
  } else {
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log("Error getting document: ", error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working. With your code I get this error message: "NOT_FOUND, This document doesn't exist. Check doc.exists to make sure the document exists before calling doc.data()." I tried adding "console.log(querySnapshot.exists);" and got back "undefined". It sounds like my query was bad. Any ideas?

Comment: If you check out the `QuerySnapshot` documentation I've linked to, you will see that it does not have an `exists` property, so it will always be undefined. I've put together a short article that might clarify some things: https://medium.com/@scarygami/cloud-firestore-quicktip-documentsnapshot-vs-querysnapshot-70aef6d57ab3

Comment: That works! I upvoted your Medium article, it was very clear.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my project. First of all there have to be an object in your database that match with the .where('objectid',==, 'object.id') then it is possible to get your data to loop. Like querysnapshot.docs.forEach((d) => d.data());